# Show message in div after saving

Tags: javascript

I save some data in my MYSQL database, after saving I wan't to show a text in my div with id #msg. Can somebody help me.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnAdd").click(function (e) {
                /* Retrieving value from textboxes */
            var besproken = $('#besproken').val();  
            var afspraken = $('#afspraken').val();  
            var coachings_id = $('#coachings_id').val();
            var verlengen = $('#verlengen').val();
                $.post("save_coaching.php", { 
                  besproken: besproken, 
                  afspraken: afspraken, 
                  coachings_id: coachings_id,
                  verlengen: verlengen
               }, function (data) {

                    $("form")[0].reset();
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Try `$("#msg").html("<p>Successfully added a record.</p>");`.

Comment: whats the problem? Just add the logic to update dom after response has returned, as @uom-pgregorio suggested. I think the real question for you is `how to update dom using jquery`.... which can be easily found and probably has 1000 SO questions on it.

Comment: Also - here's the documentation for what you need: http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

Answer (score 0):

Just use the .html( ) method on your #msg div:

```
$.post("save_coaching.php", { 
  besproken: besproken, 
  afspraken: afspraken, 
  coachings_id: coachings_id,
  verlengen: verlengen
}, function (data) {
    $( "#msg" ).html( data );
    $("form")[0].reset();
});
```

This is assuming the data variable is a simple string.  If it's JSON you'll want to use JSON.parse( data ) to convert it back to an object, and then print out the properties you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have few options todo this, for example You can control visibility by CSS.

```
$.post("save_coaching.php", { 
  besproken: besproken, 
  afspraken: afspraken, 
  coachings_id: coachings_id,
  verlengen: verlengen
}, function (data) {
  // place code here to manipulate showing the notification div
});
```

For manipulate code, You can write:

```
document.getElementById('#msg').style.visibility = 'visible' or 'hidden'
```

visible or hidden is depend on what You want todo with your #msg element.